# Iwconfig is not giving expected ouput

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, parrot-os

I have installed Parrot OS on my VM and everything seems to be working fine except for one issue. When I type `iwconfig` in the command prompt, it shows `No wireless extensions.` However, when I attempt to ping Google, it works as expected.

I expected to see that my Parrot OS is successfully connected to the network. I am using a Bridge network connection. Could someone please explain why `iwconfig` is not detecting any wireless extensions despite the network connectivity being functional?"

When I type `ipconfig` and press enter it shows the following error message:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.
enp0s3    no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: `enp0s3` — is a PCI ethernet device. Are you sure you have WiFi and not cable ethernet connection? Also the rule of thumb is post questions in text format. Images are **highly** discouraged.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and yes I am sure that I have WiFi. Do you have any solution to this problem?

Comment: There is no information in your question that suggests what you are sayng.

Comment: What else information do I need to provide?

Comment: Whatever prooves that you indeed have WiFi hardware (up and running).

Comment: (Note, if you want to notify users about your new comments, add @USER to them. It is by luck I have checked this question again.)

Comment: @0andriy When I search something using firefox in the same Virtual Machine it is working as expected.

Comment: So, you have a VM, where you have a **virtual** wired Ethernet and you are trying Wi-Fi? Don't you see the problem?